# Hadoop and Cassandra integration how to

Tags: hadoop, configuration, cassandra, integration

I have set up Cassandra on a cluster. I have set up Hadoop on the same cluster. They both work fine individually. Architecture aside, how does one go about integrating the two? What configurations should be put in which `.xml`s?

From what little documentation I have read, I think I need a class that provides the `cfs:///` scheme, right? CFS is supposed to substitute HDFS, right?

All the docs I managed to find are either too abstract, outdated or both, even the offical docs. I'm using Casandra 2.1.0 and Hadoop 2.5.1.

Comment: are you looking to have hadoop tools use cassandra instead of hdfs? If you're looking for Hadoop like functionality on top of cassandra, take a look at Apache Spark. Spark runs on top of hadoop too, and open up a lot of doors.

Comment: I think that Hadoop is better for our use case, but I will check it out, nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

Pls. check the attached link. Hope this helps.

[Cassandra Hadoop Integration](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HadoopSupport)

Also pls. check Chapter 12 of this book

[Casandra Definitive Guide - Oreilly](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920010852.do)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I checked the first one long before posting here. A colleague of mine said that he will lend me the Hedoop Definitive Guide, which I'm looking forward to. In the meantime I will try to get hold of Cassandra's Definitive guide, but seeing it's 4 years old raises some doubts.

Comment: Cassandra's changed a LOT since then. If you're looking for a good book, check out Ruth's training material: http://www.amazon.co.uk/Apache-Cassandra-Hands-On-Training-Level/dp/1500548391/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1412329641&sr=8-1&keywords=cassandra+ruth